# String.Replace and Regex.Replace not working with special characters inside IComparer

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, replace, icomparer

The following console app works fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string plainx = "‘test data’ random suffix";
        plainx = Regex.Replace(plainx, @"‘", string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(plainx);
    }
}
```

However its giving me trouble in an ASP.Net application.. I am attaching a screenshot of the VS Debug watch window and Immediate window

<sub>(Click for larger view)</sub>
[image]

As you can see, the `Regex.Replace` in the `Immediate Window` works - but somehow it is not working in the code (line 71). I've also used `String.Replace` without success.

**Edit**
It seems the value that was stored in the DB is something than what the editor shows... kind of weird.. [image]

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Regex`.

Comment: what is  the language used in  your code

Comment: What if you tried replacing `"\u2018"`?

Comment: Try looking at `testx` and `testy` in the Watch window to see what the values are after your changes. Also, what is the expected result? How do you know that the result is wrong?

Comment: Hi @SLaks I've also used string's Replace method in lines 68/69.. I will paste that code in the Edit shortly..

Comment: @JulieShannon - the language is C#

Comment: @DanielGabriel - testx still contains the leading apostrophe ("‘test data’ random suffix"). I want that ‘ to be removed so that the sorting works in the intended way..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - that worked! - what do you think might be the issue?

Comment: The quote in your code is not the same quote in the string you are testing. I just used the hex value returned from `testx[0]` to guarantee that we are using the correct quote. Added it as an answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain.. all through the code I've used the copy-paste from the watch and debug windows to get the [‘] - I haven't typed it anywhere (In fact I don't yet know how to type that from a standard windows keyboard)... Also worrying was how the same code in the "Immediate Window" was removing the character..

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quote in your code is not the same single quote in the string you are testing.

Use the hex value returned from `testx[0]` directly to guarantee that we are using the correct quote.

```
plainx = Regex.Replace(plainx, "\u2018", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you actually examined the text being compared? What Unicode code points does it contain?

Your code shows you trying to replace the glyph `'‘'`, which is a left "smart quote". The character's name is LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK and its code point is 0x2018 (aka `'\u2018'`). This is a character you can't ordinarily enter on a keyboard.

What you are probably seeing is the glyph `` '`' ``, a "backtick". Its character name is GRAVE ACCENT and its code point is 0x0060 (aka `'\u0060'`). This is the character typed when you press the [unshifted] tilde key on a standard US keyboard (leftmost key on the number row).

It might, of course, be any of a number of other characters whose glyph is similar to a single quote. See [Commonly Confused Characters](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/characters/#single) for more information.

Comment: Better than my answer, thanks for the more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace :

```
@"‘" to @"\‘"
```

---

code :

```
string plainx = "‘test data’ random suffix";
plainx = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(plainx, @"\‘", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(plainx);
Console.Read();
```